# Basement window coverup leaking

Tags: basement, leak, flooding

This house is in need of a lot of work. The biggest problem I have right now is the basement flooding. Had new gutters put in in the past month which helped a little but my biggest issue now is where past owners must have patch up the windows in the basement with some more concrete.

As you can see in the pictures, the water comes in throughout the cracks from where they placed the block of concrete to the foundation. There are two of these patches on the same wall in the basement. There is no French drain or anything going around the house. So my question is, what would be the best way to take care of this for the long run and not just a temporary fix?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't tell from so far away how the window openings were closed up. Is that masonry or something else?

Comment: I have added a closer image to show detail

Comment: Good, but I still can't tell. What are we looking at? Concrete or wood framing?

Comment: The concrete foundation in the basement.

Comment: I asked specifically about the patch in the window opening.

Comment: the answer is obvious .... remove the patch and install a new one that is properly sealed ..... also reroute the neighbour's downspout